# Can you force derived class from a bass class to define specific member variables in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, base-class, python-class, abstract-base-class

If I have a class say:

```
class BaseClassOnly():
    def __init__(self):
        self._foo = None

    def do_stuff(self):
        print("doing stuff with foo" + self._foo)
```

I want to force all classes derived from BaseClassOnly to provide a value for 'self._foo' so that the inherited function do_stuff() will be able to use it. Is there a way to ensure if a class that inherits from BaseClassOnly with result in an error if the variable self._foo is not set in init()?

Comment: I think it would be hard to do because there would be no way without introspection of the class `__init__` code. Much easier to force people to implement a method or `property`, then it's trivial without getting into too much black magic

Comment: But in general, you would simply document this for the consumers of the class

Comment: abstract base classes can force subclasses to implement a method.  This is typically considered cleaner than forcing subclassees to implement a field.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the child classes will call the base class's `__init__()`, you could use `hasattr()` to check.

```
class BaseClassOnly():
    def __init__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_foo'):
            raise ValueError('self._foo must be defined')
```